# Pass whole row as parameter of DataGridTemplateColumn Hyperlink

Tags: wpf, hyperlink, mvvm-light, datagridtemplatecolumn

Is it possible to pass a whole row as a parameter for the Hyperlink of DataGridTemplateColumn?

```
<my:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name">
  <my:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock>
        <Hyperlink Foreground="Black" TextDecorations="None">
          <Run Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </Hyperlink>
      </TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>
  </my:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</my:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to tell what you are trying to achieve but a ComandParameter binding without a value should give you the row eg

```
<Hyperlink Foreground="Black" TextDecorations="None" CommandParameter="{Binding}" Command="{Binding methodThatHandlesTheHyperlinkClick}"> 
      <Run Text="{Binding Name}" /> 
</Hyperlink>
```

Comment: Noticed, you are new to Stack Overflow.  It works well when you mark the answer as accepted rather than just a comment (assuming the answer was what you were afer of course) see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work